# Pattern Exception when using Lookahead Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Regex to validate conditions in a string, I wrote it on an online regex validator, but when I use it in my Java code I get an exception:

```
"(^([a-z]{1,6})(?(?=(_))(([_])([0-9]{0,4})?)|[a-zA-Z]{0,})[a-zA-Z]{0,}?@sample[.]com)"
```

The exception is Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 16
(^([a-z]{1,6})(?(?=(*))(([*])([0-9]{0,4})?)|[a-zA-Z]{0,})[a-zA-Z]{0,}?@sample[.]com)

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please at least tell us what this regex is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^([a-z]{1,6})(?(?=(_))(([_])([0-9]{0,4})?)|[a-zA-Z]{0,})[a-zA-Z]{0,}?@sample[.]com)
               |  
               ^ --- if clause is not supported in JAVA
```

Your problem is because of this `(?(?=)`.

If you meant it to be non capturing group than it should be `(?:(?=)`

Java do not support [**if clause**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) `(?(?=))`. PCRE supports this.